# How to stop a loop and restart it when a button is clicked?

Tags: loops, python-2.7, button, tkinter

I'm working with tkinter, I have a for loop that prints something every turn. I would like to stop it every turn while a the next button is not pressed. (Like with a `raw_input()` in console mode.)

Like this :

```
user click button next --> print 0, then stop 
user click button next --> print 1, then stop 
user click button next --> print 2, then stop
```

How can I do this easily?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make a generator function:

```
def gen_int():
    n = 0
    while True:
        yield n
        n += 1
```

Then you can initialise it (`gen = gen_int()`) before the loop and simply call `print next(gen)` each time a button is pressed.

Comment: looks to fit perfectly to my problem, Im gonna test and will tell you. Thanks